# Why my python socket HTTP client can`t close

Tags: python, sockets, httpclient

I am new to the network programming and I try to write a script to implement a HTTP client server.Following is my code.

```py
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(('www.baidu.com', 80))

request_line = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n'
request_header = 'Host: www.baidu.com\r\n'
request_blank = '\r\n'
request_str = request_line + request_header + request_blank

client.send(request_str.encode('utf-8'))

flag = 0
with open('baidu.html', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while True:
        data = client.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        if flag == 0 and data.find('\r\n\r\n') != -1:
            loc = data.find('\r\n\r\n')
            data = data[loc + 4 :]
            flag = 1
            f.write(data)
        elif flag == 1:
            f.write(data)
client.close()
```

The question is the `break` seems not working. This script can not end automatically.

Comment: unless you send `Connection: close` header, the default is `Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: You need to actually parse the server's response to differentiate between the response headers, the actual file data, and the end of the response (especially when HTTP keep-alives are being used). The current reading code is not sufficient to handle this correctly. See my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on this matter. But, is there a reason why you are not using [Python's built in HTTP client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) instead?

Comment: I am following a tutorial to build this HTTP client, which teaches me with `socket`. Anyway, I've figured out how to close the http client. Thank you so much for your guidance!